# i need to filter array of object, filteration happend on condition startwith and string contains

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my array of objects.
I need to filter this by name.

Case one: When I search for 'tali', the filter result from startwith case, same time user enter 'tali Co OP' get the result 'Taliparamba Co Op Hospital'.

Case two: When I search 'ath' I want to get result of   'Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai' and 'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi' because Ath is contain in 'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi'.

```
 test = [{ id: 1, name: 'Taliparamba Co Op Hospital' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi' },]
```

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried some case got it but some case not

Comment: Let us know what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const test = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Taliparamba Co Op Hospital' },
      { id: 1, name: 'Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai' },
      { id: 1, name: 'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi' },
    ];

    function search(arr, str) {
      const regexp = new RegExp('\\b' + str.split(' ').join('.*?\\b'), 'i');
      return arr.filter((item) => regexp.test(item.name));
    }

    console.log(search(test, 'tali'));
    console.log(search(test, 'tali Co OP'));
    console.log(search(test, 'ath'));
```

Comment: hi i get first two case 'tali' and tali co ho but i didnt get when i type 'ath'  only show Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai

Comment: the issue is when i type 'Ath" i need to display both 'Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai' and  'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi'

Comment: @sam Is correct now?

Comment: no @spike the client need this second case also

Comment: @sam I'm not sure what you real want, can you give me some test case?

Comment: case is if i enter 'Ath'  all words start with Ath and the word contain 'Ath' also want eg : we have  'Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai' and 'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi' 
client search Ath  return these two strings beacause  'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi' this contain ath (atholi)

Comment: @sam I think you may miss something else. Because I'm very sure the `RegExp` can match both 'Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai' and 'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi'

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const test = [{ id: 1, name: 'Taliparamba Co Op Hospital' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi' },]
    
const myString = "ath"; // your search string goes here
const result = test.filter(eachObject => {
    return eachObject.name.toLowerCase().search(myString) !== -1
})

console.log("result is", result)
```

Comment: when i type ath not getting those two

Comment: @sam The above DanteDX's code is working correctly. You would have been making some mistake I think.

Comment: let me check again

Answer (score 0):

I think below line of code should do the job for you

```
const test = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Taliparamba Co Op Hospital' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Athikkal Saw Mill,Kallai' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Marhaba Ice Plant Atholi' },
];

const searchedStr = 'Ath'
const results = test.filter(obj => 
    obj.name.includes(searchedStr) || 
    obj.name.includes(searchedStr.toLowerCase())
);

console.log(results)
```

Please let us know how it goes